# How to get data of post on facebook like comments, picture by graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I using graph api to post picture to wall of user, after get postid i try to get post data by graph api follow this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/postid?access_token=my_access_token
```

But result return only has message, created_time, id

```
{
   "created_time": "2015-09-10T01:52:18+0000",
   "message": "test",
   "story": "Minh D\u01b0\u01a1ng added 2 new photos to the album: test_demo_app Photos.",
   "id": "507382632760376_508325799332726"
}
```

So, how to get other data of post such as comments, picture in story, likes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the docs first. Since v2.4 you have to specify each field you want to be returned from the Graph API. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields

> **Declarative Fields**
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, `GET /v2.4/me/feed` no longer includes likes and comments by default, but `GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes` will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

Comment: Oh sory, i forgot it ^^.